# How to rotate axis correctly using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two coordinate frames which have an offset and rotation between them.

Using the following example I tried to visualized it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (4,0)  node[right, text width=5em] {$X$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,4)  node[right, text width=5em] {$Y$};

    \begin{scope}[rotate=0,draw=red]
        \draw[->] (3,2) -- (7,2)  node[right, text width=5em] {$X'$};
        \draw[->] (3,2) -- (3,6)  node[right, text width=5em] {$Y'$};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[->, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, text align={center},text={${\overrightarrow{R}}{\;}$}}}] (0,0) -- (3,2)  node[right, text width=5em] () {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: rotate_0]

once i change

```
\begin{scope}[rotate=0,draw=red]
```

to

```
\begin{scope}[rotate=20,draw=red]
```

I get:
[image: rotate_20]

How could I place the origin of my X'Y' coordinate frame at position (3,2) in my XY coordinate system?

In addition I would like to place $\overrightarrow{R}$ a bit higher. How could I place it above the vector?

Comment: @koleygr, you are right. I haven't seen that question. In my question I ask in addition about the position of $\overrightarrow{R}$

Comment: I have answered in the comment for this... You will find out there that the rotation of a node doesn't follow the rule that caused the previous problem to your figure (It rotates around the node's center and not around (0,0) by fefault)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rotate, is using by default the point (0,0):
See here the orange arrow that is the arrow R rotated by 20 degrees:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (4,0)  node[right, text width=5em] {$X$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,4)  node[right, text width=5em] {$Y$};

    \begin{scope}[rotate=20,draw=red]
        \draw[->] (3,2) -- (7,2)  node[right, text width=5em] {$X'$};
        \draw[->] (3,2) -- (3,6)  node[right, text width=5em] {$Y'$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \draw[->,orange,rotate=20] (0,0)--(3,2);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[->, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, text align={center},text={${\overrightarrow{R}}{\;}$}}}] (0,0) -- (3,2)  node[right, text width=5em] () {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So you have to change the default point (the center of the ratation) and this can be done with the command: `rotate around` like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (4,0)  node[right, text width=5em] {$X$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,4)  node[right, text width=5em] {$Y$};

    \begin{scope}[rotate around={20:(3,2)},draw=red]
        \draw[->] (3,2) -- (7,2)  node[right, text width=5em] {$X'$};
        \draw[->] (3,2) -- (3,6)  node[right, text width=5em] {$Y'$};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[->, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, text align={center},text={${\overrightarrow{R}}{\;}$}}}] (0,0) -- (3,2)  node[right, text width=5em] () {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @koleyger, very nice answer. Do you have a tip how how to place the $\overrightarrow{R}$ a bit higher?

Comment: `\draw[->] (0,0) -- (3,2)  node[midway,above,rotate=40]  {$\overrightarrow{R}$};`

Comment: @koleyger, now it is perfect! Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome @Eagle... Happy TeXing...